# Network.framework for peer to peer connection in background mode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wifi-direct, network.framework

Developed iOS application using Network.framework to share data among iOS devices and its working fine. But there are few scenario where its failing to share data :

1. IF two devices wanted to share data using WIFI direct ( no bluetooth ) , keeping both devices operating in Foreground mode its working fine but as soon as one of the devices putting application in background mode , data sent from other devices not receiving ( even after coming from background to foreground )
2. If airoplane mode is enabled and then try to sync then it not able to send data.

I have raised this question on Apple Developer community , here is the link for more information : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715118?login=true&page=1#729483022

Comment: iOS apps can't maintain network connections when they are not in the foreground.  Note Eskimo's point in your developer forum post.  When you say background you actually talking about the suspended state.  Apps can perform networking when they are running in the background but network operations on their own are not a background execution reason. You need something else to trigger your app in the background like location services, audio etc. misuse of these background modes will result in App Store rejection.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for your response , but my app is for internal purpose not for public store.

Comment: Then you could try a “hack” like playing silent audio in the background.